# Saving state of toggle switcher with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML-site which is running on two different PCs with some toggle switches from `metro.css` in it. I'm trying to save its state with `localStorage` through an `onclick`-method.

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch_104_02" checked="checked" onClick="switcherFunction(this.id)">
    <span class="check"/>
</label>
```

This is the JS-Function:

```
function switcherFunction(switcher_id) {
    if (switcher_id.checked == true) {
        localStorage.setItem(switcher_id, false);
        localStorage.getItem(switcher_id);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem(switcher_id, true);
        localStorage.getItem(switcher_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: The JS is just client-side (manipulates the DOM) - you would need to connect the website to a backend to save the state of the toggle

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
<input type="checkbox" id="switch_104_02" checked="checked" onClick="switcherFunction()">

function switcherFunction(){
    if($('#switch_104_02').is(':checked') == true){
        localStorage.setItem("switch_104_02", "false");
        localStorage.getItem("switch_104_02");
    }else{
        localStorage.setItem("switch_104_02", "true");
        localStorage.getItem("switch_104_02");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please debug it by putting console.log() to check if it go in function and in which condition
I tested in my local system and it is working for me

Comment: it is going in the function and in the condition but its not saving the state when I open the file a second time

Comment: actually it is working,i get the right state in the console but its not saving the state when I call the page another time. do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: sorry but I have no idea about it